# Strange Inconsistent rendering in Chrome

Tags: html, google-chrome

i have a website with alot of popup windows and z-index going on.
Chrome version: 46.0.2490.80 m (never seen in other browser, but cannot omit it)

Everything works fine, but every 50th (not precisely, but very rarely when opening popup or coming back from alt-tab)

Behind all this: my website.
The red: the fullscreen overlay beneath my popup.
The lightGray: my popup window.
The darkgray: popup content.

[image]

So for some reason, the corner of my div is cut off. The problem is not connected to this particular popup, or this particular corner.

I have sometimes seen this following an alt-tab into chrome, but not enough to say that's the problem.

I have never seen anything like this, usually it works or breaks, this time its working breaked.

Any clues?

Comment: Could be any number of things. We don't know what's generating the popup (I assume some JavaScript plugin?) or what HTML it's generating. We need more context to be able to really be able to help. Alt-tabbing into Chrome shouldn't require a redraw so that seems like a bizarre cause.

Comment: It's all too big to cut into a question here, i just had a hope anyone had seen something similar..

Comment: But please, fill me in on those "number of things"

Comment: this "number" seems to be equal 0 ?